# How many ajax files should I have?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm starting out php.
I'm wondering how many ajax files should I have. Should I have a seperate one for each operation I want to do? each query insert etc,
Or do I like send something in the data, or maybe request that ID's the request so that the server knows what to do?
Is there a good example for that?
I don't know if it matters but I'm using jQuery.

Comment: Look at using a REST-based system on the server, in which case the request type provides the CRUD operation to perform. That would probably be a good pattern for you to start with.

Comment: for each ajax one php or use mvc (model view control) to handle all your methods in one file... or switch on a specific parameter

Comment: So I'm getting that it just depends on the way I want my system to be like.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, I personally like having as many files as possible (with fewer lines of code), but keeping related functions groupped in an object inside the same file.

For example, you could have one file called `userAjax.js` which contains the userAjax object:

```
var userAjax = {

   getUserLevel : function (userId) {
      $.get // blah, blah, or any ajax request
   },

   setUsername : function (userId, username) {
      $.get // blah, blah, or any ajax request
   }

};
```

In your app you could then use (after including the `userAjax.js`): 
`userAjax.setUsername(37, "John");`

I like using this method because it keeps code structured, you do not have too much code for too little functionality. I use it in small to medium sized projects and works great :) (both for production & maintanance).

For the server-side, you could either do the same thing, or simply have a file for each command. I also like file-per-command method because if you structure your files in folders it's very easy to maintain the code (you can go directly to the function you want by navigating through the file tree). But again, for larger projects I think you should use a more OOP-approach, like having a class with many functions in a single file.

To sum it up, it all depends, mostly based on the size of the project.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can create functions for all operations what you want to do, and handle this functions with one file. Or you can create as many as want files for handling requests. If you are using some framework built on MVC architecture, you will probably use only one file (Controller) or more functions in more controllers, it is really variable, depending on usage.

There is lot of tutorials how to use PHP with AJAX. You just need only search for them.